# Passing structured data between ABAP sessions?

Tags: memory, abap

It is generally known that ABAP memory (EXPORT/IMPORT) is used for passing data inside ABAP session across call stack, and SAP memory (SET/GET) is session independent and valid for all the ABAP sessions of user session.

The pitfall here is that SET PARAMETER supports only primitive flat types, otherwise it throws the error:

> "LS_MARA" must be a character-type field (data type C, N, D or T). by

Global assignment like `ASSIGN '(PrgmName)Globalvariable' TO FIELD-SYMBOLS(<lo_data>).` is not always a way, for example if one wants to pass structure to some local method variable.

Creating SHMA shared memory objects seems like an overkill for simple testing tasks.

So far I found only [this ancient thread](https://answers.sap.com/answers/8758060/view.html) were the issue was raised, but the solution from there is stupid and represents a perfect example of how you shouldn't write, a perfect anti-pattern.

What options (except DB) do we have if we want to pass structure or table to another ABAP session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same application server, you may use [`EXPORT/IMPORT ... SHARED BUFFER/MEMORY ...`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abencrosstrans_app_buffer_glosry.htm).

Probable statement for your requirement:

```
EXPORT mara = ls_mara TO SHARED BUFFER indx(zz) ID 'MARA'.
```

Between application servers, you may use [ABAP Channels](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_channel_glosry.htm).

Comment: I got [this](https://imgur.com/a/kiLuJTQ) when I tried to export `mara` structure in such a way: `EXPORT mara = ls_mara TO SHARED BUFFER mara(sc) FROM ls_mara ID 'mar'.`. Did I specify buffer argument correctly? I used the sample [from this help section](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abapexport_data_cluster_medium.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_5@5@)

Comment: You must use an [export/import table](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenexport_data_cluster_indx.htm). You may copy the table INDX to ZINDX for instance, and use `EXPORT mara = ls_mara TO SHARED BUFFER zindx(zz)` ("zz" or whatever you want). In case you ask, using SHARED BUFFER/MEMORY, the table is used as a support of storing the data in memory, nothing is stored in the table (something is stored only with `TO DATABASE`).

Comment: thanks, it worked, added more detail for future visitors. is there a way to check it in debugger? [in system areas in export](https://imgur.com/Nt9eP3b) I do not see my value

Comment: I don't know a way to display the extended memory via the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

As usual Sandra has a good answer.

`Export/Import To/From  Shared buffer/Memory` is very powerful.
But use it wisely and make sure you understand that is is on 1 App server and
is non persistent.
You can use rfc to call the other app servers to get the buffer from other servers if necessary.  CALL FUNCTION xyz DESTINATION ''

See function `TH_SERVER_LIST` .   ie what you see in SM59 Internal Connection.

Clearly the lack of persistency of shared buffer/memory is of key consideration.
But what is not immediately obvious until you read the docu carefully  is how the shared buffer manager will abandon entries based on buffer size and avaliable memory. You can not assume shared buffer entry will be there when you go to access it. It most likely will be, but it can be "dropped", the server might be restarted etc. Use it as a performance helping tool but always assume the entry might not be there.
Shared memory as opposed to shared buffer, suffers from the upper limit issue, requiring other entries to be discarded before more can be added.  Both have pros and cons.

In St02 , look for red entries here, buffer limits reached.
[image]
See the current parameters button that tells you which profile parameters need to be changed.

A great use of this language element is for logging or for high performance buffering of data that could be reconstructed . It is also ideal for scenarios in badis etc were you can not issue commits. You can "hold" info without issuing a commit or db commit.
You can also update / store your log without even using locking.
Using the simple principle the current workprocess no. is unique.

```
 CALL FUNCTION 'TH_GET_OWN_WP_NO'
  IMPORTING
    wp_index = wp_index.
```

Use the index no as part of the key to your data .

if your kernel is 7.40 or later see class `CL_OBJECT_BUFFER`
otherwise see function `SBUF_OBJ_SHOW_OBJECT`

Have fun with Shared Buffers/Memory.
One major advantage of share buffers over share memory objects is the ABAP Garbage Collector. SAPSYS Garbage collection can bite you!

Comment: `Shared memory as opposed to shared buffer, suffers from the upper limit issue` so why not to use buffer always? Manual memory clearing is an additional hassle without any notable gain. What is the use-case for `SHARED MEMORY`?

Comment: I use shared buffer always and not Shared memory.  But If you place too much info in the buffer, the algorithm used to remove entries is not as simple as the docu alludes to. In high volume situations whole chunks of the memory can be just dropped. I got burnt using it in a productive scenario. The job and  time to recover encroached dangerously on a migration window. The loss info was critical and had to be recalculated. Just got away with it.   Its just a warning....and just passing that on... Drinking from fire hydrants does that to you. Can tell you more offline if interested.